# Django: Url translation is wrong

Tags: python, django

I have the following translation:

```
{% url 'admin:organizers:settings:index' request.organizer.slug as business_settings_url %}
{% blocktrans trimmed %}
    Looking for <a href="{{ business_settings_url }}">business settings</a>?
{% endblocktrans %}
```

However, I always get the wrong url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/everett-vega-and-davis/survey-test/settings/%E2%80%9C/admin/everett-vega-and-davis/settings/%E2%80%9D

It should be
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/everett-vega-and-davis/survey-test/settings/

Do you see what I am doing wrong here?

**urls.py extract**

```
app_name = "organizers"
urlpatterns = [
    # Don't change the order, otherwise the url will be overwritten by <slug:organizer>
    path("organizer/create/", views.OrganizerCreate.as_view(), name="create"),
    path(
        "<slug:organizer>/",
        include(
            [
                path("", views.OrganizerIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
                path(
                    "settings/",
                    include(
                        (
                            [
                                path(
                                    "", views.OrganizerSettings.as_view(), name="index"
                                ),
                            ],
                            app_name,
                        ),
                        namespace="settings",
                    ),
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Organizer(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey()  # PROTECT = don't allow to delete the user if an organizer exists
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True, validators=[SlugBlackList()], verbose_name=_("Event series link")
    )
    [...]
```

Comment: Can you share your relevant `urls.py`, together with the model and how you populate the `slug`? It looks like you somehow mix up parts.

Comment: The `%E2%80`, etc. are quotes, like `“`. So it looks like `request.organizer.slug`, is not a valid slug.

Comment: Is it maybe not allowed to use `href` in translations?

Comment: I added the urls.py

Comment: If I take the <a href party before the translation, it works. That's what is confusing me